# Provide PDFs via links to a blob storage or by controller action?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-blob-storage

I want to know:

Does it make more sense to store the PDFs on a blob storage and then link to the PDF or make the PDFs available on a controller action?

What are the pros and cons? What should I look?

Excuse my bad english and thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the PDFs are static (not dynamically generated based on the request), then it makes sense to store them in blob storage.  It will be more efficient, plus you could easily distribute the content via Microsoft's CDN.

Answer (score 0):

If you put the PDFs in Blob Storage and linked directly to them, that would work. But if you link it to a controller action (assuming you're talking about an MVC web app), you can track which PDF's are requested AND link to the PDF. It just depends on what you're trying to achieve.